# Displaying Mathml equations

Tags: mathml

My browser, Firefox 3.6, seems to display the Mathml equations in the W3C test suite just fine. But if I copy the code into my webpage, like from [here](http://www.w3.org/Math/testsuite/build/main/General/Math/mathAdisplay2-full.xhtml), all Firefox produces is something like `x y x y`  instead of how it correctly rendered the W3C page. What am I missing here>

**EDIT**: I just tried it in Chrome and Chrome failed the test itself by rendering it as `x y x y`. Needless to say, it rendered the math in my own webpage the same.

**EDIT 2**: I tried it on a new html document. Doesn't work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<math display="inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" mode="display">
  <mfrac>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
  </mfrac>
    </math>
    <math display="block" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" mode="inline">
  <mfrac>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
      </mfrac>
    </math>
  </body>
</html>
```

I swear the W3C equations render just fine though...

Comment: It says viewed 0 times, and yet there's already an upvote and a favorite. You there, Jon Skeet? edit: nvm, refreshed the page again and now there's 2 views

Comment: FWIW, you page renders fine in my Firefox 3.6.12. Just almost twice wider then the image.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/views-indicator-inaccurate-shows-one-views-on-question-with-two-close-vote

Comment: @cababunga what do you mean by "my" page? The W3C page renders fine in Firefox too for me...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you gave a link to your page that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting your file in a filename named `mml-prb.xhtml` works. Note the extension.

Comment: Things have changed greatly ever since. Current Firefox renders HTML5 with embedded MathML just fine.

Answer (score 9):

Including

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

and then using

```
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <mroot>
            <mrow>
                <mi>x</mi>
            </mrow>
            <mn>4</mn>
        </mroot>
    </math>
```

works in Chrome and Firefox

**Update:**

Since the mathjax cdn is shutting down, change

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.7-latest/MathJax.js?...">
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?...">
</script>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 2):

as others have said you need to serve as xml for FF3, if you want to use mathml-in-html5 served as text/html you need firefox 4 (or webkit nightlies)

Answer (score 0):

You should use xml and serve it as such (i.e. use correct mimetype), which means you have to use xhtml and mathml tags with proper namespaces. Take how W3C serves the example as an example.

**Note:** HTML5 is *NOT* xml