# Unable to render MathML content in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, mathjax, mathml

I have some MathML contents in HTML page and the page needs to be rendered in Google Chrome over HTTPS connection. So i tried to follow the approach said in the below link

[Displaying Mathml equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174277/displaying-mathml-equations)

but it did not work (I copied the script in my HTML page). Then I tried to install the MathJax plugin for chrome as an extension to Google Chrome. That seemed to render some of MathML in my file but for some I got an error. I found that MathJax can render Presentation MathML contents but cannot render Content MathML contents (I have both types of contents in my page). Also it did not work over HTTPS connection. It will be very helpful if I get some workarounds to solve this problem.

Regards,
Anirban

Comment: Call `MathJax.Hub.Configured()` after the endof the `<body>` tag...

Comment: Answered already given here , Please Check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26105113/1372951](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26105113/1372951)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The question linked to in the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174277/displaying-mathml-equations) is somewhat dated and describes how to include MathML in xhtml (not html since that was not actually valid back then). With HTML5, it's much easier to include MathML.

Chrome does not support MathML so you'll need a polyfill. MathJax can render both Presentation and Content MathML; see the relevant documentation at http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/ .

However, the author needs to configure MathJax correctly to do so. FYI, plugins in the Chrome store are made by third parties; also, MathJax works over https just fine if done correctly.

Below is an example that shows how to enable all MathML features MathJax can provide, including the `mml3.js` extension for experimental features.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fullest MathML support using MathJax</title>
  <script>window.MathJax = { MathML: { extensions: ["mml3.js", "content-mathml.js"]}};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <math display="block"> 
    <apply> 
      <plus/> 
      <ci>a</ci> 
      <apply> 
        <minus/> 
        <ci>b</ci> 
        <ci>c</ci> 
      </apply> 
    </apply> 
  </math> 
  <math display="block">
    <mrow>
      <mi>a</mi>
      <mo>+</mo>
      <mrow>
        <mi>b</mi>
        <mo>-</mo>
        <mi>c</mi>
      </mrow>
    </mrow>
  </math>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With this method, no error is getting thrown but many of the contents are coming as "none". Like the equation "1+2=" is coming as "1none+none2none none ="

Comment: also mml3 is still experimental, can you kindly suggest me anything which can be used in production? It would be really helpful.

Comment: Also I need to run the same thing in Chrome and Safari, the contents are getting displayed correctly in Safari, will they be affected after adding these extensions?

Comment: For your first comment, I can't say much without some code samples. For the second, you don't need the mml3.js extension. For the third, MathJax supports all browsers and platforms equally so yes it should work.

Comment: I've updated the answer since cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, cf. https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/.

Comment: It would be better to include the script only in Chrome/Edge, because Firefox supports MathML natively. (Safari not tested.)

Answer (score 3):

This worked really well for me when i was in a similar situation..

Add these scripts in the `<head>`

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Config({
  config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
  jax: ["input/TeX","input/MathML","output/HTML-CSS","output/NativeMML"],
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js","mml2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js"],
  TeX: {
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"]
  }
});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.0-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

Then,

add this `<script>` after the closing of the `<body>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  MathJax.Hub.Configured()
</script>
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html)

or

you can see this wonderfull example.. https://math.stackexchange.com/ .. Check the source of math.stackexchange..It will be really helpfull..

**UPDATE**

See page no 54 in this [link](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/mathjax/latest/mathjax.pdf)..It says

> MathJax supports the MathML3.0 mathematics tags, with some
>   limitations. The MathML support is still under active development, so
>   some tags are not yet implemented, and some features are not fully
>   developed, but are coming. The deficiencies include:
>
> • No support for
>   alignment groups in tables.
>
> • Not all attributes are supported for
>   tables. E.g., columnspan and rowspan are not implemented yet.
>
> •Experimental support for the elementary math tags: mstack, mlongdiv,
>   msgroup, msrow, mscarries, and mscarry. (Via the mml3 extension, see
>   below.)
>
> • Experimental support for bidirectional mathematics.

Comment: I tried doing it this way, some of the contents were rendered correctly, but for some, I am getting the following error

Unknown node type: mstack

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is possible to render MathML inside Chrome with the help of a CSS and by using HTML5, i.e. a Chrome version that supports unknown tags.

As an experiment, including some baby step fiddling with contenteditable="true" to test HTML5 editing, I was using this CSS here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/MathML_Project/test-mathml-css

Chrome Example without the CSS:

> [image: without CSS]

Chrome Example with the CSS:

> [image]

Source files are here:
https://gist.github.com/jburse/fb43afd01048feac7028b5642817af0a#file-mathml-html

Answer (score 1):

This chrome extension is simple and elegant:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/math-anywhere/gebhifiddmaaeecbaiemfpejghjdjmhc/related?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try my Chrome extension "HTML + MathML":
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fmath-html-%2B-mathml-solut/emdjdpchbjipnjhkfljbcapgfecmnglm?hl=en-GB

or my solution for "All Browsers":
http://www.fmath.info/formula/js/allBrowser.jsp

regards